# Enable scrolling for NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, scroll, row, nstableview

I've added a NSTableView in a NSScrollView IB in Xcode 4. Its controller class is displaying data whose horizontal length  exceeds its row width. However, no horizontal scroll bars appear, so do we have to enable them?

(the table only has one column with no headers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data width is not the determining factor if horizontal scrolling will be enabled. You need to ensure the NSTableColumn is wider that the NSTableView for horizontal scrolling to be enabled.